# CometD on WAS: ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet cometd

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, cometd

I just deployed a CometD project, wich was working fine in Jetty to WAS 8.0.0.8.
The application installs and starts, but upon startup throws the following exception in the SystemOut.log:

```
[26.08.14 13:35:06:062 CEST] 00000031 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet cometd: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.upgrade(WebSocketFactory.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketFactory.java:396)
at org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport.handle(WebSocketTransport.java:106)
at org.cometd.server.CometdServlet.service(CometdServlet.java:165)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3774)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)ServletWrappeServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exceptionServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:214)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:703)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:682)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
... 36 more
```

The Application seems to start, connects to the client, receives and sends a message and then stops. If I refresh the page, the same happens.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Edit: Why does the application make use of jetty.websocket? The reason I am using cometD is, that I thought it does not use Websocket since WAS below Version 8.5 do not support those.

Edit: Here the content of the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transports</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>initializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.primer.BayeuxInitializer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The folder web-inf/lib does not exist in my project. I build it using maven.

Comment: Seems like you have configured CometD to explicitly use the WebSocketTransport ? Unfortunately your question lacks the required information to answer, like Jetty / CometD versions, configurations, etc.

Comment: I am using the most recent CometD V 3.0.1 and the Jetty that comes with it (I believe it's Jetty 9?) What configurations should I provide?

Comment: Please provide at least `web.xml` configuration, and content of `WEB-INF/lib`. The fact that CometD tries to run the JSR 356 WebSocket transport makes me think there is a problem with your webapp classpath, so that CometD thinks JSR 356 is available while it's not. How do you build the war ? Manually ? Maven dependencies ?

Comment: I edited the web.xml in. Is this line the one, i should be looking at?  <param-value>org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport</param-value>

Comment: In CometD 3, the `transports` parameter indicates _all_ the transports, not the additional ones like it did in CometD 2. 
This is documented in the [migration docs](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_migration). 
I don't think WAS 8 supports JSR 356, so defining only the JSR 356 WebSocket transport is not going to work. Just remove this parameter, and CometD should just work.

Comment: Yup. Thats what did it! Thank you!